# Why is the return value of a Promise undefined when the value inside the Promise is defined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise, constants

In the following code snippet:

```
1 const GetErrors = async (projectScanID: number, projectName: string) => {
2   try {
3       console.log("fetching errors")
4       const errorsFetch = await fetchErrors(projectScanID);
5       console.log("errorsfetch:", errorsFetch)
6       await setErrors(errorsFetch);
7       console.log("errors", errors)
8       setIsErrorsFetchComplete(true);
9       console.log("errors: ", errors)
10  }
11  catch(e) {
12      enqueueSnackbar(`Could not load errors! Error: ${e}`, {variant: 'error'});
13  }
14}
```

My console.log on line 5 is displaying that `errorsFetch` is undefined, despite the Promise in the fetchErrors function I'm calling on that line console.logging the error data on line 6:

```
1 export const fetchErrors = async (project_scan_id: number): Promise<IError[]> => {
2     let errors = <Array<IError>>[];
3     let string_project_scan_id: string | null = String(project_scan_id)
4     ///fetches error data
5     return Promise.resolve(errors).then(function (value) {
6         console.log("value:", value)
7     }).catch(function (error) {
8         console.log("Error")
9     });
10    }
11}
```

Notice how I'm using `await` in the first code snippet to wait for `fetchErrors` then again to wait for `setErrors` to finish on line 6 before `setIsErrorsFetchComplete(true);` on line 8. Why is my constant I'm using to retrieve my return value from `fetchErrors` undefined on line 5 of the first code snippet?

Edit: `errors` and `isErrorsFetchComplete` are states defined in the higher scope before calling `GetErrors`.

Comment: You don't return anything in `.catch`, so it implicitly returns `undefined`.

Comment: The promise with `console.log("value:", value)` doesn't return anything

Comment: @tarkh they are?

Comment: Where are you defining `errors` inside `GetErrors`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox you right, just missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `Promise` resolves to a value:

```
Promise.resolve(errors)
```

*But*, you chain onto it here:

```
.then(function (value) {
  console.log("value:", value)
})
```

So `value` in this callback has your `errors`, but then this doesn't resolve to anything.  It essentially "swallows" the resolved value.  You can return it from this as well though:

```
.then(function (value) {
  console.log("value:", value);
  return value;
})
```

The same is true of the `catch` callback.  If invoked, the resulting `Promise` chain wouldn't resolve to anything unless that callback function returns something.

---

The second question doesn't make much sense to me given the code shown.  Nothing here is "displaying" anything.  And the terminology implies the use of React, which isn't shown here at all either.  This probably merits a separate question entirely, once the Promise chaining is sorted out.